# When Should a Question be Closed?  [Part 1]?

Tags: discussion

To help us identify questions that should be closed, I thought it would be a good idea to highlight the questions ***that should definitely not be closed.***

To help eliminate confusion on what should be closed, and to help inspire *you* to take action and help make our site great, I've picked a great, recent question that I believe highlights the criteria a question should meet in order to get our +1's.

[What Lightweight/Project Management or Bug Tracker Software Can I Use to Manage Exceptions, Milestones, and Old Bugs?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/4947/34)

This question, asked under the [pm-software](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pm-software) tag, has many aspects that make it great:

- This describes a specific problem. The three important criteria in picking software that solves the problem are displayed in three easily digestible bullet points.
- There's clear background information about what type of environment the question-asker is working in. Since every PM situation is different, it's important to know this information so the right answers are posted.
- It has clear background information, which eliminates the polling type answers that tell us nothing about *why* a specific answer will help us.
- The question title is to the point, describes the problem from a high level overview, and may be more easily searchable on Google.
- It contains facts related to the question-asker's situation, which again leads to more helpful answers that solve a specific problem in project management.

Thus, this question will definitely not fit into the `Not Constructive` close category:

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

- What did I miss?  What other points, from the [FAQ](https://pm.stackexchange.com/faq), do you think make this a great question?
- Based on what's in the [FAQ](https://pm.stackexchange.com/faq), would you close this question? If so, why?

Comment: I agree with your points above; I don't think it should be closed.  However, I wavered over the "flag" link because even with all of the above being true, since there are a lot of questions with the `pm-software` tag I would've liked to have seen some specific nod to why this wasn't a duplicate of some others.  Just a basic "I looked at X, Y, Z questions and the answers there were close, but my difference is..."  I think I'm in "beggars can't be choosers" territory, though -- *I* have to remember that almost but not great is still *very good*!

Comment: We currently get about 2.5 questions per day, so you're right that beggars can't be choosers. By being more careful with what we do allow on the site, I wonder if that could help increase the traffic, or strangle the site. I know there are a lot more project managers out there in the world. The question I ask myself is: How can we produce good content that will get them to come here?